# Web Application for testing post requests

Tags: post, developer-tools

Is there a web application for testing post requests? What I imagine it'd be like is you would visit the site and then it would redirect you to a unique URL. You could then send a post request to the URL which would display the request after it was received.

Comment: why wouldn't you just log the request and watch the log books with e.g. `cat ./foo.log`?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative from Microsoft: [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21625)

[POST request instruction](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161611.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it would be more along the lines of what you're looking for:

[http://www.htttools.com](http://www.htttools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Rest Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) is a Firefox Add On that I have used in the past as an Http Post/Get testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

The "net" tab in the Firebug plugin for Firefox will show you the contents of all requests including POSTs. You can also intercept and modify them with TamperData.

Fiddler will do the same for Internet Explorer and other windows programs. Wireshark will also show this information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches. If you want to do automated browser-based testing, you could use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)/Java or [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/)/Python. Alternatively, if you want to perform white-box testing, you can write scripts that make a http post request to the web application (e.g. using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) if you are using Python), obtains the response and verifies that the response is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) allows you to create a temporary URL and view the last twenty requests.

Answer (score 0):

With [PutsReq](http://putsreq.com) you can test requests and simulate responses using JavaScript.